# Laptop Clicking sound

Tags: laptop, maintenance

I've recently heard a sound from my laptop that concerns me.

Every 5 seconds, something inside (not the speaker) will make 4 quick clicks in roughly 1/4 second.  It will be silent for 5 seconds, then repeat again.

To me, it sounds like a hard-drive head resetting in a way that would indicate a drive problem, but this laptop has an SSD drive!  So it should definitely not be a mechanical drive.

If it were a fan-problem, I'd expect the sound to be continuous, not at 5 second intervals.

Is there anything else that would be a candidate for such a strange noise?

The laptop seems to be running fine; I'm not aware of any problems with either reliability, heat, performance, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try finding the source:

- Plug in headphones, to determine if it's from the audio system. BTW, some cell phones radiate a connection-attempt signal that can be heard through PC audio, so keep cell mobis away.
- Open the laptop and use a piece of plastic tubing as a stethoscope to determine where the clicks originate. (That's also useful to find rattles in a car.)
- Check the Event Log to see if the noise coincides with an event.
- Remove the battery, running only on AC adapter -- the noise might be a discharge warning.

Comment: Good ideas:  1.) Nothing from audio system.  Also keeping cell phones away and off seems to have no effect..  2.) Reluctant to open a company laptop.  3.) Nothing in Event Viewer stands out. 4.) This is a newer, thin laptop, without a removable battery, but the noise persists with/without the AC adapter plugged in.

Comment: Is there an access panel for RAM/SSD that you'd be able to open? If not, moving the "stethoscope" to different vent holes could hint what's underneath, using the repair manual to show parts locations.